# Java: Can't append textArea

Tags: java, methods, applet, textarea, textfield

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    input = textField.getText();
    textArea.append(input);
    textField.setText("");
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

This method works and will append the variable input whenever the method is called.

```
public void start(){

    System.out.println("Starting");
    int questionNumber = 0;
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    counter = pickQuestions();
    System.out.println("here");
    textArea.append("**Applet**");
    System.out.println("now here");
    doQuestion(counter, questionNumber);

}
```

This method does not work, and does not append "**Applet**", however it does print "here", and then "now here".

Does anybody know a possible reason for this or have I not given enough information?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any (null pointer) exceptions?

Comment: If `doQuestion` blocks (meaning that `start` doesn't return), the UI will be frozen and `textArea` won't update. Add a `println` after the call to `doQuestion` to test whether it gets past that call.

Comment: It does print out. I think the problem was what Software Monkey said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in the second case you are updating a GUI component from a thread other than the GUI Event Dispatch Thread.  Any manipulation of a GUI component must be done from the EDT.

To do this in AWT, inject a custom [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) into the [EventQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) using `invokeLater()`.

Comment: Hmm... because I have System.out.println's throughout the class file, and I wanted to change them to textArea.append's